# Unexpected route name in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I have 3 controllers on my spring app. Each one of them have different name then I set up for example I have

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/operator")
public class OperativesController {
```

and when run it on localhost and check available routes this is my output

```java
{
  "_links" : {
    "operativeses" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/operativeses"
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if someone would tell me that where this name is coming from?

PS. yesterday everything was all right.

Not sure if that is helpful for you but below you can find my `properties`

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2016Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

**EDIT**
I just debug this spring app and find out that, my path are created from "Entities". So I have entity names `Operatives` and spring picking up it as URL, so it automatically creating path like `operativeses` (why? I do not know) because I change name of this entity to 'Operativesasd' and in the result I have path 'Operativesasds' (notice s on the end)

So my question now is, Why my spring app creating path base on entities even if I have controllers?

my entity looks like

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="operatives", schema = "lm")
public class Operatives implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name", length=150)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "level", length=7)
    private String level;
    @Column(name="is_qa", length=50)
    private String isQa;
    @Column(name="is_active", length=5)
    private String isActive;
    @Column(name="is_admin", length=50)
    private String isAdmin;

    
    public Operatives() {
        super();
    }

    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    
    public void setId(int aId) {
        id = aId;
    }

    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    
    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    
    public void setLevel(String aLevel) {
        level = aLevel;
    }
    
    public String getIsQa() {
        return isQa;
    }

    
    public void setIsQa(String aIsQa) {
        isQa = aIsQa;
    }

    
    public String getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    
    public void setIsActive(String aIsActive) {
        isActive = aIsActive;
    }

    
    public String getIsAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    
    public void setIsAdmin(String aIsAdmin) {
        isAdmin = aIsAdmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added ```spring-boot-starter-hateoas``` dependency?

Comment: no I do not have that. Do I need it? I never have to use it and in other project I am working on I do not using it as well and everything is working fine.

Comment: any URL mapping with name ```operativeses``` left by mistake on any controller?

Comment: no like I said above, I have only three controllers and check them all, there is no requestMapping with operativeses